# Spark explode function not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to flatten a complex XML structure , below is the XML file -

```
<root>
<ATS  name="exp_Change_Rec">
<EXP1>
<EXP1INT >
<ExPFLDs>
<ExPFLD  precision="10" name="COL1" output="true"/>
<ExPFLD  precision="20" name="COL2" output="true"/>
<ExPFLD  precision="30" name="COL3" output="true"/>
<ExPFLD  precision="40" name="COL4" output="true"/>
</ExPFLDs>
</EXP1INT>
</EXP1>
</ATS>

<ATS  name="exp_Change_Flag">
<EXP1>
<EXP1INT >
<ExPFLDs>
<ExPFLD precision="10" name="COL5" output="true"/>
<ExPFLD precision="20" name="COL6" output="true"/>
<ExPFLD precision="30" name="COL7" output="true"/>
</ExPFLDs>
</EXP1INT>
</EXP1>
</ATS>
</root>
```

I am expecting the output as -

```
Name                  Value
exp_Change_Rec        COL1
exp_Change_Rec        COL2
exp_Change_Rec        COL3
exp_Change_Rec        COL4
exp_Change_Flag       COL5
exp_Change_Flag       COL6
exp_Change_Flag       COL7
```

I am executing via databricks spark xml but it's creating some sort of Cartesian join -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.databricks.spark.xml.
val df1 = spark.read.option("rowTag", "root").xml("file:///home/sv-infopcdq/spark/sample.xml")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("_name", explode($"ATS._name"))
df2.withColumn("COL_NAMES", explode($"ATS.EXP1.EXP1INT.ExPFLDs.ExPFLD")).show(100)

+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
|                 ATS|          _name|           COL_NAMES|
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
|[[[[[[[, COL1, tr...| exp_Change_Rec|[[, COL1, true, 2...|
|[[[[[[[, COL1, tr...| exp_Change_Rec|[[, COL5, true,],...|
|[[[[[[[, COL1, tr...|exp_Change_Flag|[[, COL1, true, 2...|
|[[[[[[[, COL1, tr...|exp_Change_Flag|[[, COL5, true,],...|
```

Here I see COL1 is getting issued with both exp_Change_Rec and exp_Change_Flag.
Any suggestions please.

The output is working fine when I was trying to explode one column , however when I tried to explode all the columns it's showing Cartesian join

Like if I wan the output as

```
  Name                   Value    Precision
    exp_Change_Rec        COL1      10
    exp_Change_Rec        COL2      20
    exp_Change_Rec        COL3      30
    exp_Change_Rec        COL4      40
    exp_Change_Flag       COL5      10
    exp_Change_Flag       COL6      20
    exp_Change_Flag       COL7      30
```

If I want to extend the correct answer to include "precision " in it , its not working -

```
xml_df.withColumn("_name", ($"_name"))
    .withColumn("COL_NAMES",explode($"EXP1.EXP1INT.ExPFLDs.ExPFLD._name")
.withColumn("COL_NAMES",explode($"EXP1.EXP1INT.ExPFLDs.ExPFLD._precision")).drop("EXP1")
      .select($"_name".as("Name"), $"COL_NAMES".as("Value"))
```

Any workaround to explode multiple columns on same level please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to explode multiple columns is to use

```
df.select(explode(arrays_zip($"col1",$col2))).select( $"col.*").show(20,false)
```

This solution is available from 2.4+

Answer (score 1):

*In the  First place, your `rootTag` and `rowTag` you need to correct to proceed further. Since you used `rowtag` as parent/root tag i.e.(`root`) it was considering entire XML as one record... thats where you are getting single chunk of records not seperated record format... See the below implementation details.*

---

I have used `explode` function and I select exact column you wanted like below...

```
 val xml_df = spark.read.
      format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "root")
      .option("rowTag", "ATS")
      .option("nullValue","")
      .load(f.getAbsolutePath)
      xml_df.show
    xml_df.printSchema()

   val test =  xml_df.withColumn("_name", ($"_name"))
    .withColumn("COL_NAMES",explode($"EXP1.EXP1INT.ExPFLDs.ExPFLD._name")).drop("EXP1")
      .select($"_name".as("Name"), $"COL_NAMES".as("Value"))
    test.printSchema()
    test.show(100,false)
```

Expected Output by you :

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                EXP1|          _name|
+--------------------+---------------+
|[[[[[, COL1, true...| exp_Change_Rec|
|[[[[[, COL5, true...|exp_Change_Flag|
+--------------------+---------------+

root
 |-- EXP1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EXP1INT: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ExPFLDs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ExPFLD: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _output: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _precision: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _name: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+-----+
|Name           |Value|
+---------------+-----+
|exp_Change_Rec |COL1 |
|exp_Change_Rec |COL2 |
|exp_Change_Rec |COL3 |
|exp_Change_Rec |COL4 |
|exp_Change_Flag|COL5 |
|exp_Change_Flag|COL6 |
|exp_Change_Flag|COL7 |
+---------------+-----+
```